# node.js redirecting to S3 pre-signed url results in SignatureNotMatch

Tags: node.js, redirect, amazon-s3

I am attempting to redirect the query to an S3 asset (image/png in this case) using the following code:

```
var params = {
    Bucket : bucket,
    Key : category.icon
}
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
if (url)
{
    //return res.status(200).send({url : url})  /// works fine
    //return res.redirect(url)                  /// does not work
} else {
    return res.status(404).end()
}
```

While the first line (res.status(200)) works fine, and I get the signed url that I can later access, I would prefer to redirect directly to the url. However, using the redirect method, I keep getting Amazon's "SignatureDoesNotMatch".

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, in principle, it should work fine.  Can you capture the `Location:` header that's getting returned?  It could be related to escaping (or not, or double-escaping) of `/` `+` `=` characters in the signature, assuming S3 Signature Version 2.

Comment: The issue turned out to be the Content-Type header for the request that I set up and forgot about. Thanks for making me check, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the Content-Type header for the request that I set up and forgot about. When I removed it, everything works fine.